# Cannot center <div> element

Tags: html, css

I try to center a div element ( the footer div in this case ) in my webpage but it insists on staying on the left side.

I am not quite sure what is wrong... Any ideas?
Thank you in advance.

HTML :

```
<div id='main'>
</div>

<div id='footer'>Centered Text</div>​
```

CSS :

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin:  0;
    font-size:   12px;
}

body {
    font-family: helvetica, serif;
    font-size:   12px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

#main {
    border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
    margin: 3% 5%;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

#footer {
    font-size: 75%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/DjPjj/2/

Comment: It's beautifully centered in my Firefox...

Comment: Centered in Chrome as well. What browser are you testing in?

Comment: Do you mean vertically centered...?

Comment: Really? I am using Chrome as well but it's not centered

Comment: Please write a better question which fully explains what you want and includes your code when the jsFiddle link goes dead.

Comment: The fiddle is fine (albeit a little confusing) the top is centered, but the footer (denoted with the words "centered text") is **not**. In other words, the question is how to center the footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it won't center is because of the `positon: absolute;`.

Keep in mind this means that the footer will always be at the bottom of the page, even if the content overflows past it.  It will overlap.  If you want to have it be attached to the bottom of the page, you must set the min-height of a container above it to 100% and then deal with a negative margin-top and remove the `position: abosolute;`

http://jsfiddle.net/4fuk7/1/

Notice how the centered text is overwritten.

If you are looking for something to always be at the bottom, this would work
http://jsfiddle.net/4fuk7/3/

Sorry, the last one would scroll to the top. This one doesn't, but you'd need to fiddle with it a bit to get it to properly align around the margin's you've set. http://jsfiddle.net/4fuk7/9/
http://www.tlunter.com/Layout 2/ is where I did something similar.  You can reference that if you want.

Comment: This looks good, however if there is no text the footer goes to the top of the page. How can I keep it to the bottom in that case?

Comment: Give me one second, I have that in another fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/DjPjj/13/

Try this:

```
#footer {
    font-size: 75%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Because your footer is absolutely positioned, you must tell it what width to take relative to its parent container. You can then use text-align to center the text within it.

Here is another example: http://jsfiddle.net/DjPjj/17/

This one centers a box within the absolutely positioned element. The inner box can be centered using `margin: 0 auto` because it is not absolutely positioned.

```
#footer {
    font-size: 75%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}

#footerInner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

This is more flexible because the inner element gives you a new container to work with that is centered relative to the parent.
​

Comment: Yeah, you can't mix `margin: 0 auto` with `position: absolute` because it takes it out of the flow of the document.